# SQL Dependency OnChange not being invoked

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014, sqldependency

I am trying to get notifications on table update by using SQLDependency in my code. For this, as a reference, I downloaded the code from this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events). I used my database instead of Chatter, as given in the article. The issue is that the message Send event doesn't fire Onchange SQLDependency event. Also, I see a row in the queue with message_sequence_number as -2, after I close the application.

Is there some settings that I am missing in the database, which is required for Onchange event to fire ? I will appreciate any help.